# Why is there no list index out of range error in my Python program?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and have been learning only for a week so please pardon me if the answer seems really obvious to those of you who are experienced. I have written a simple program as follows and don't understand why I don't get "error: list index out of range".

```
def sum13(nums):
    sum=0
    for i in range(1,len(nums)):
        if nums[i]==13 or nums[i-1]==13:
            sum=sum
        else:
            sum=sum+nums[i]
    if len(nums)>=1:
        if nums[0]==13:
            sum=sum
        else:
            sum=sum+nums[0]
    return sum

print(sum13([]))
```

When using the for loop in the function `sum13(nums)`, I indicated `range(1,len(nums))`, and index 1 doesn't exist in an empty list. Why is there `no error: list index out of range` when I use the function `sum13(nums)` on an empty list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because

```
>>> len([])
0
```

and

```
>>> range(1, 0)
[]
```

<sup>(or an empty `range` object in python3)</sup>

so the loop doesn't perform any iteration and the access on `nums[i]` is never executed.